# image in div with z indexes

Tags: html, css, z-index

There is my code :

```
<div class='f-left vignetteFamille box-sizing'>
    <div class='relative contenuVignetteFamille box-sizing' style='z-index:1;'>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <img class='absolute' src='./charte/famille/fondBasGaucheVignetteFamille' style='bottom:-21px;left:-4px;z-index:0;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my div `contenuVignetteFamille` hover the image but this doesn't work and I don't know why

EDIT:

there is my css but I don't know if will help you :

```
.vignetteFamille{background-image:url('./charte/famille/fondVignetteFamille.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:bottom right;margin-right:16px;width:201px;margin-top:2px;padding-bottom:19px;padding-right:19px;}
.contenuVignetteFamille{width:100%;border:solid 4px #FFC600;}
```

Comment: Please show us your css, or create a jsfiddle. And notice, z-index is only effect, when element has `position` property.

Comment: I have add my css but I don't know if will help you

Comment: need more css. what is `absoulte` and `relative` `box-sizing` selectors?

Comment: just 
position:absolute / position:relative / box-sizing: box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but I'm assuming you want to highlight the image when hovering the `div contenuVignetteFamille`?

This can be solved by adding css to the child when hovering the parent, like this:

```
.contenuVignetteFamille:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[See my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mbsy9p0b/)

On another note, don't use `br` tags to get some height on your `div`, add a `height` value instead. I've also moved your inline styling to the external one.